# Swift: infinite pages in UiCollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, carousel, infinite

I am playing with amazing project found on Git : https://github.com/ink-spot/UPCarouselFlowLayout

I am trying to create an infinite carousel. Meaning it will start from the first item after the last one.

I was trying to amend collectionView - cellForItemAtIndexPath method with code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(CarouselCollectionViewCell.identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CarouselCollectionViewCell
    let character = items[indexPath.row]
    cell.image.image = UIImage(named: character.imageName)


    if indexPath.row == items.count - 2 {

        items.insert(items[0], atIndex: items.count)
        items.removeAtIndex(0)


        //self.collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0)])
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    return cell
}
```

My idea was to update source array moving first element to the end. But it is not working.

Also I have a question, how can I amend code to see 2nd element in the center after program loads? So that It would show 2nd element and will have 1st on the left and third on the right.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this (SwipeView)](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView.git) library on github. I have used in my projects as well. set following property for infinite scrollview.

```
self.swipeView.wrapEnabled = true
```

It is very easy to use. Try it your self.

And if your bound to use UICollectionView if might wanna visit this tutorial [here](https://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2013/07/building-a-circular-gallery-with-a-uicollectionview/). This explains how can you implement Infinitely-Scrolling  with UICollectionView.

Comment: yes it uses UICollectionView and your link wont help as it requires cells fill the full width of the collection view’s frame. In my example one element is in the center and two from left and right